# What is the best sword for maximum DPS in Hypixel Skyblock?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-hypixel-skyblock

What is the best weapon for maximum DPS in Hypixel Skyblock (non-ability weapion - melee)? There have been a lot of discussions and votes online, including [this vote forum](https://hypixel.net/threads/strongest-sword-in-hypixel-skyblock-2022.4753472/), but I can't seem to determine which one is the best.

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically, I guess it would be the EM Blade because money = damage but you would have to be super rich to deal the most DPS (**D**amage **P**er **S**econd) with it.

Comment: Unfortunately the em blade has a cap at 2b coins purse